# Dynamic Form validation in RectJS

Tags: reactjs, forms, validation, formik, react-hook-form

I have a form setup with stepper in `ChakraUI`. I get input from user and map those fields to `helloSign` template. Now I have like 20 templates which will  require different fields for each template.

for example: I have steps like step: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7

- **Template A** needs input from steps : 1, 2, 5, 7
- **Template B** needs input from steps : 1,2,6,
- **Template C** needs input from steps: 3, 4, 6, 7

and also in each steps I also hide or show fields based on template type (Form Type). like in both template A and B, Step 1,2 is common but fields inside those steps can be different. some may be required in **Template A** but same will be option in **Template B**.

I have already made those forms and they are working fine for all templates.. Now I am stuck at validation part. how to validate all those fields based on form type. how to change validation dynamically.

All steps are independent, I mean `<form>` tag is not used anywhere and next button is not inside steps. Next button is outside all those steps inside parent component. Is there any logical help or guideline you guys can give? how would I do using formik or react hook form etc?